# The uniqueness of fundamental solution on $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, heat-equation

Let $p_t(x,y)$ be a non-negative fundamental solution to the heat equation on $\mathbb R^n$ which satisfies for all $y\in \mathbb R^n$:

$(i) (\partial_t -\Delta_x )p_t(x,y)=0, \text{ }t>0, x\in \mathbb R^n,$

$(ii) p_t(\cdot, y)\rightarrow \delta_y, \text{ for }t\downarrow 0,$

$(iii) \int p_t(x,y)\,dx$ is finite for any $t>0$.

Can we conclude that $p_t(x,y)=\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}\exp\{{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4t}\}}$?

Comment: Yes, it's a theorem of Widder that any nonnegative solution of the heat equation (for positive time) is the convolution of the Gaussian kernel with a positive measure.  And (ii) suffices to identify that measure as a point mass.  I will try to add more details when I have time.

Comment: Laurent Saloff-Coste and I wrote about this theorem, in a more general setting: https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1926 http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10959-013-0484-1.  The introduction and references may be helpful.